# What's the difference (if any) between these two types of PEX-to-copper fittings?

Tags: plumbing, pex

There are two kinds of similar fittings to transition from copper pipe to PEX tubing. Here's an example:

[image]

The first is made from copper and looks to be "formed" ie bent / pressed into shape in a mold.

The second is made from brass and looks to me to be machined.

But does it make any difference which of these two types is used? It seems like they will both function identically and be installed the same way.

---

Note - I'm not concerned about the specific brands, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

It certain makes a difference - apparently 70 cents.

Functionally, no difference, or possibly (hard to be sure from the small images and I'm not going to bother to hunt down the parts elsewhere) the brass is set up / sized to be a  male part for soldering into a female copper port, while the copper appears to be a female copper port to have a male copper pipe soldered into. The machined exterior on the brass part leans that way, but could simply be the way it's made. *i.e.* depending on what size the part is, it appears that it could be either.

Edit to add: the brass might also be slightly shorter, but that seems unlikely to matter 99.9% of the time.

Comment: They were both female sweat fittings. The "machined" type you can also find in a male variant, but I don't think I've seen the other done that way,.